# What methods exist to verify if my tax return was received by the IRS?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, income-tax-refund

I finished my taxes on February 15th.  However, TurboTax had a bug that prevented e-filing.  I waited until the 22nd, and when it still wasn't fixed I just mailed a paper copy of my taxes.

I started checking the "Where's my refund" tool on the IRS website in early April.  It is now almost 50 days since I mailed the return in, but the online tool just says "We cannot provide any information about your refund."

I tried calling the refund hotline at 1-800-829-1954, but it was just an automated tool that gave the same information as the online form.  I then tried calling the more general number provided, 1-800-829-1040, but there were no relevant options except one that filtered me into the automated system provided at the first number.

Is there any other way to contact the IRS to verify that my return was received?  If it's not been received I would like to send another copy asap not just to avoid late penalties, but because we need the refund for a time sensitive matter.

What other methods are available to check the status of the refund?

Comment: Two related links: https://www.taxpayeradvocate.irs.gov/news/nta-blog-getting-rid-of-the-kryptonite-the-irs-should-quickly-implement-scanning-technology-to-process-paper-tax-returns/ and https://www.irs.gov/newsroom/irs-operations-during-covid-19-mission-critical-functions-continue

Comment: "not just to avoid late penalties" There are no late penalties if all the taxes have been paid by the tax return due date (April 18, 2022).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For paper filing the way to go is with *certified* USPS service. This is the only legally binding proof of mailing if any dispute arises, and also provides tracking for you to check when the envelope was physically delivered to the IRS. Once delivered, it may wait for *months* to be opened and scanned into the system, and only then and not before the "where's my refund" system will show your refund and your account will show the return as filed.